# Android: How to add two views to one activity

Tags: android

I have a program where I want to add two views in one activity, like

```
 public class AnimationActivity extends Activity {
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(new GraphicsViewForBitmap(this));
        setContentView(new GraphicsView(this));


    }
}
```

where GraphicsViewForBitmap & GraphicsView are two classes extends view.
so I want at a time two views should set to an activity.
Is it possible?
Plz give me answer.
Thanks

Comment: How you want your both view place horizontally, vertically or overlapping one another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but first you have to put them inside a ViewGroup, for example a LinearLayout, and then set that ViewGroup with setContentView. Because with the existing code you're not just appending the second view with the first, but you are setting another content.

Answer (score 6):

`setContentView()` will display only the view that you have set . If you want to display more than one view then you can add both the view in your layout XML file inside any Layout like `LinearLayout`,`RelativeLayout`  etc. Then you can use `setContentView(R.layout.yourXML)`.

Here is how you can do it in your XML...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.yourpkg.GraphicsView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>


<com.yourpkg.GraphicsViewForBitmap
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
  
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the second view to the first view.

```
LinearLayout childLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
childLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

childLayout.addView(graphicsView);    
parentLayout.add(childLayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create a 2nd layout XML, say **main2.xml** (the 1st being **main.xml**). Then you can swap from one to another via, e.g. an ActionBar button, etc. as follows:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main2); // Pass from layout #1 to layout #2 
setContentView(R.layout.main);  // Pass from layout #2 back to layout #1
```

(You can create as many views as you like ...)