# Using two setContentView in one activity class

Tags: android

I have the following code where MyClass basically extends View. I was wondering if I need to use both `setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainlcass_app)` and `setContentView(myDrawing)` to show the 2D graphics that I draw in MyClass.

```
public class MainClass extends Activity {
    MyClass myDrawing;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainlcass_app);

        myDrawing = new myDrawing(this);
            setContentView(myDrawing);
            myDrawing.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to implement like this ? You can set multiple views in the same activity but you need to inflate it based on some condition . You can not inflate two views at the same time as you are doing.

Comment: you can use addContentView for your custom view to be drawn on top ov the view inflated from xml..Have you tried that..?

Comment: Thanks @PuruPawar You saved the day... Totally new to canvas and draw here

Answer (score 2):

No, You can't do that. The second layout will override on the parent view.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was not sure if I can do that.

Answer (score 2):

In you main layout (`activity_mainlcass_app`) just add `MyClass`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.example.MyClass
        android:id="@+id/myclass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.example.firstactivity
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>


<com.example.secondactivity
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

For more information check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248177/android-how-to-add-two-views-to-one-activity) and this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194102/is-it-possible-to-have-more-than-one-setcontentview-in-one-class)

Answer (score 0):

If you want new drawing on top of other (with different layouts sizes maybe) use FrameLayout for original layout and use gravity to position new drawing and use addView methods of activity.